# CSS Dynamic Left/Right column Static Width

Tags: html, css, dynamic

The problem is, i have a background in two parts.

```
Background Image #1
Background Image Repeats (endlessly) #1
Background Image #2
Background Image Repeats (endlessly) #2
```

In css you cant create a background by just sticking elements on it like so:

```
#leftColumn {
    background-image:url('http://i53.tinypic.com/2ezlb7n.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right top;
    background-z-index:1;    

    background-image:url('repeat.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;  
    background-z-index:0;
}
```

What I want the result to be:

```
[ BACKGROUND LEFT ]
[ CONTENT ] 
[ BACKGROUND RIGHT ]
```

The content should always be 768px. The background on both sides should show as much as possible.

---

I can't believe it, but i was able to solve it myself. This is the code that made it possible:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
}

#leftColumn {
    background-image:url('http://i54.tinypic.com/aa83lw.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;  
    display:none;   
}

#rightColumn {
    background-image:url('http://i52.tinypic.com/kcjdwi.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
    display:none;   
}

#leftImage {
    background-image:url('http://i53.tinypic.com/2ezlb7n.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    width:100%;
    height:128px;
}

#rightImage {
    background-image:url('http://i56.tinypic.com/noh6on.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:128px;
}

#content {
    width:768px;
    background-color:#666666;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:769px) {

    #leftColumn, #rightColumn {
        display:table-cell;
    }

}

</style>

<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
    <td id="leftColumn" align="right"><div id="leftImage"></div></td>
    <td id="content">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="rightColumn" align="left"><div id="rightImage"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: step one, do not use tables! working on a solution for you.

Comment: What's the purpose of the left and right blocks?  If it's just for adding in a background, please say so - I can give you an alternate design that works more easily than this.  And like @jimplode suggests, this deign won't have any tables.  You don't want/need them for this.

Comment: I understand your problem from a `horizontal` point of view, but I have no idea what you want to happen `vertically`. For instance, is that green bar aligned to the bottom of the page? The bottom of the viewport?

Comment: You guys are the best! I have been trying so hard to figure this out, hope you will be able to find a solution. The background is not necessary for the site content, but if the space is available because the screensize is larger then 768px it should show as much background as possible.

Comment: You know you can centre backgrounds??

Comment: give the table the background image, and add in another div v-align="bottom" to do the second part of the image.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you're wanting to have a content area in the center with a background that spans the width no matter how wide it runs.

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">your center content goes here</div>
</div><!-- close wrapper -->
```

The CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background: #FFF url(/images/widebackground) repeat-x center top;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 auto; /*centers div - change the 0 if you want a different top margin*/
    width: 768px;
}
```

This will repeat your background horizontally.  It will be centered in the window.  If your image is wide enough (4000px, maybe?) you're unlikely to see it repeat on any display without several monitors.  You can also set a color for any areas not covered vertically, or visible through transparent areas.  I set this to #FFF, but you can choose your color or leave it out.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mtfT/1/) demonstrating what I am suggesting.  I changed a few things (colors, content size) to make it more visible, but the key parts are still there.

Comment: This is how I would do it for backgrounds.

Comment: Wow jsfiddle is nice!! I will try and make an example there of my problem. The thing is the background consists of a couple of elements that makes it difficult. (1) Left and right should have different background images. (2) Left and right have and image and a repeating image that just repeats untill the entire screen is filled.

Comment: Then the only other way of doing it is with javascript and set the element widths dynamically.

Comment: Do you know how to make this? <DIV1 DYNAMIC WIDTH><DIV2 CONTENT WIDTH=768><DIV3 DYNAMIC WIDTH>. So that if the screen would be 1024 it will automaticly make DIV1 and DIV2 about 128px

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in ff, but does not work in Chrome, sarafi or IE.

So is probably no good for you!! :)

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
    body
    {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .centre
    {
        display:table-cell;
        height:400px;
        width:768px;
        text-align:left;    
        margin:0px auto;
        position:relative;
        background-color:#FF0000;
    }
    .left
    {
        display:table-cell;
        background-color:#00FF00;
    }
    .right
    {
        display:table-cell;
        background-color:#0000FF;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="left"></div>        
    <div class="centre">
        <p>This is the centre content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The left and right part are not absolute 100pixels in width. They should fill the empty space on the left and right side of the content.

Comment: Copy my (wrong) code and see what it does when you make the screen smaller, it will cut the background image more as you make it smaller.

Comment: I will create a better example, one sec.

Comment: yeah, just realised that. Is this simply for the background?? As you can do that as a background image on the body.

Comment: Ah I just noticed you edited the code, ye I am looking in Chrome and Safari and there it does not work. See that's the reason i am using tableview cause it works in all browsers :-)